Cartesian product without reuse
I have two generators producing data, for example:
def xs():
    yield [1, 2]
    yield [3, 4]

def ys():
    yield [5, 6]
    yield [7, 8]

And I want to process all possible (x,y) pairs:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

I can do this:
from itertools import product

for x, y in product(xs(), ys()):
    process(x, y)

Here's the problem: process might modify the data, for example like this:
def process(x, y):
    print(f'process({x}, {y})')
    x.pop()
    y.pop()

Then what happens is this:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5])
process([3], [7])

That's because product(xs(), ys()) creates all the xs and ys only once, and reuses them. So the earlier process calls affect the data for the later calls. I need to avoid this reuse.
This is slightly better:
for x in xs():
    for y in ys():
        process(x, y)

This reuses each x but each y is created freshly, leading to:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3], [7, 8])

One way to avoid reuse of each x is to always make a deep copy:
from copy import deepcopy

for x in xs():
    for y in ys():
        process(deepcopy(x), y)

That gives the desired behavior. The trouble is that deepcopy can be much slower than freshly generating the data would be. Here are times where xs() and ys() yield 100 lists of 100 ints (and process doesn't do anything) with the above three methods:
  0.6 ± 0.0 ms  using_product
  3.1 ± 0.0 ms  nested_loops
404.7 ± 25.9 ms  with_deepcopy

How can we always use fresh x and fresh y without deepcopy, so that it's much faster? It should be possible to take only about twice as long as nested_loops, since that already produces half of all values freshly.
Benchmark/testing script:
def using_product(xs, ys, process):
    for x, y in product(xs(), ys()):
        process(x, y)

def nested_loops(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(x, y)

def with_deepcopy(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(deepcopy(x), y)


funcs = [
    using_product,
    nested_loops,
    with_deepcopy,
]

from itertools import *
from copy import deepcopy
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random

# The little example
def xs():
    yield [1, 2]
    yield [3, 4]
def ys():
    yield [5, 6]
    yield [7, 8]
def process(x, y):
    print(f'process({x}, {y})')
    x.pop()
    y.pop()
for f in funcs:
    print(f.__name__ + ':')
    f(xs, ys, process)
    print()

# Arguments for benchmark
def xs():
    for _ in range(100):
        yield [1] * 100
ys = xs
def process(x, y):
    pass

# Run the benchmark
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(xs, ys, process), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)

Attempt This Online!

Could you give a reason why process would need to modify its inputs? Seems more like a possible design flaw to me.

@LHLaurini It can have advantages, needing less time or memory or code. Actual background: It's for a test case generator for testing posted solutions for another SO question. I want to test them as-is, but some of them modify the test data.

Using a shallow copy of your lists instead of a deepcopy should do the trick:

def shallow_copy(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(x.copy(), y.copy())

Output:
using_product:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5])
process([3], [7])

nested_loops:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3], [7, 8])

with_deepcopy:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

shallow_copy:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

  0.7 ± 0.0 ms  using_product
  3.3 ± 0.2 ms  nested_loops
  9.6 ± 0.8 ms  shallow_copy
426.4 ± 24.9 ms  with_deepcopy

Python: 3.12.0 (main, Oct  7 2023, 10:42:35) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]


Only for those example cases, though. In general the data can be further nested or even have other types. That's why I used deepcopy. I guess I should make that clearer...

Your input is a couple of lists of numbers, so just use index notation or a comprehension to copy them.
def using_product_with_indexer(xs, ys, process):
    for x, y in product(xs(), ys()):
        process(x[:], y[:])

def nested_loops_with_indexer(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(x[:], y)

def using_product_with_comprehension(xs, ys, process):
    for x, y in product(xs(), ys()):
        process([xcoord for xcoord in x], [ycoord for ycoord in y])

def nested_loops_with_comprehension(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process([xcoord for xcoord in x], y)

Results:
using_product:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5])
process([3], [7])

nested_loops:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3], [7, 8])

using_product_with_indexer:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

nested_loops_with_indexer:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

using_product_with_comprehension:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

nested_loops_with_comprehension:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

  0.6 ± 0.0 ms  using_product
  3.1 ± 0.0 ms  nested_loops
  5.9 ± 0.1 ms  nested_loops_with_indexer
  6.5 ± 0.1 ms  using_product_with_indexer
 22.0 ± 1.5 ms  nested_loops_with_comprehension
 37.3 ± 2.0 ms  using_product_with_comprehension

Python: 3.12.0 (main, Oct  7 2023, 10:42:35) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]


A general solution that duplicates the data via copy would just be a reimplementation of deepcopy. An alternative solution would be to duplicate the data by running arbitrary copies of the generator:
def grid_of_generators(xs, ys, process):
  x_len = len(list(xs()))
  y_len = len(list(ys()))

  x_cache = [list(xs()) for i in range(0, y_len)]
  y_cache = [list(ys()) for i in range(0, x_len)]

  for xi, yi in product(range(0, x_len), range(0, y_len)):
      process(x_cache[yi][xi], y_cache[xi][yi])

Results:
using_product:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5])
process([3], [7])

using_product_with_indexer:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

nested_loops_with_indexer:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

grid_of_generators:
process([1, 2], [5, 6])
process([1, 2], [7, 8])
process([3, 4], [5, 6])
process([3, 4], [7, 8])

  0.8 ± 0.0 ms  using_product
  8.0 ± 0.1 ms  nested_loops_with_indexer
  8.9 ± 0.2 ms  using_product_with_indexer
 21.9 ± 0.5 ms  grid_of_generators

Python: 3.12.0 (main, Oct  7 2023, 10:42:35) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]

This should be a general solution that runs much faster than deepcopy, but the downside is that it will use much more memory and its performance is intrinsically tied to the performance of the generators. In practice, a general solution is still ill-advised, and a bespoke solution related to the structure of the data itself will still be far more efficient in terms of both memory and performance.

Right, that works in the example cases. But not in general, that's why I used deepcopy. Otherwise we could also just call process(xs[:], ys[:]).

@nocomment A single general solution that will work with anything you give to it will need to use deepcopy (or some other general purpose copying function that will in essence be a reinvention of deepcopy). Any optimizations would depend on the specific usecases, such as with your examples being a list of numbers. For instance, if it was a list of dictionaries, then you would need to duplicate both the outer list and the inner dictionary, which will be slower than this example but can still have a bespoke solution that will be much faster than deepcopy.

No, such copying isn't necessary. Note that I only deep copied the xs, not the ys, because the ys are created by sufficiently many generators. The xs can likewise be created by sufficiently many generators, and just need to be properly combined with the ys.

@nocomment The reason copying y in the nested example isn't necessary is because you are rerunning the ys generator for every element produced by the xs generator. This is still duplication of data, just in another form. There is a general solution that also reruns the xs generator for every element produced by the ys generator that will remove the need for deepcopy. But from my experimentation, it will cause the memory footprint of the program to skyrocket, not to mention a bespoke solution will still be faster.

Well, you could perhaps reduce the memory if you iterated lazily instead of putting everything into lists in advance.

I just tried with a simple selfmade deepcopy function that just distinguishes between lists and non-lists. Takes ~100 ms in the benchmark.

Posted my solutions and memory measurements now. (I btw would've upvoted your answer for its grid_of_generators solution, I just disagree too much with your last sentence.)

Instead of creating just one xs() iterator, we can create one for each y-value:
def one_x_iterator_per_y_value(xs, ys, process):
    xiters = [xs() for _ in ys()]
    for _ in xs():
        for xit, y in zip(xiters, ys()):
            process(next(xit), y)

Here, xiters holds all those xs() iterators, one for each y-value. Then for each x-value, I go through all y-values and their own x-iterators, and process the next x-value from that iterator and the y-value.
Runtimes:
  0.6 ± 0.0 ms  using_product
  3.1 ± 0.0 ms  nested_loops
  6.8 ± 0.5 ms  one_x_iterator_per_y_value
 11.7 ± 0.3 ms  grid_of_generators
102.9 ± 3.8 ms  my_deepcopy
395.0 ± 15.5 ms  with_deepcopy

That also includes grid_of_generators from @Abion47's answer as well as my_deepcopy, which is the same as the original with_deepcopy but with a selfmade less general deepcopy function that only distinguishes between lists and non-lists (so it doesn't really count, but I was curious about its performance anyway).
I also measured peak memory usage:
   169,152 bytes  using_product
     2,872 bytes  nested_loops
     3,568 bytes  with_deepcopy
     3,176 bytes  my_deepcopy
    27,296 bytes  one_x_iterator_per_y_value
17,305,624 bytes  grid_of_generators

Full script:
def using_product(xs, ys, process):
    for x, y in product(xs(), ys()):
        process(x, y)

def nested_loops(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(x, y)

def with_deepcopy(xs, ys, process):
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(deepcopy(x), y)

def my_deepcopy(xs, ys, process):
    def deepcopy(lst):
        return [
            deepcopy(obj) if isinstance(obj, list) else obj
            for obj in lst
        ]
    for x in xs():
        for y in ys():
            process(deepcopy(x), y)

def one_x_iterator_per_y_value(xs, ys, process):
    xiters = [xs() for _ in ys()]
    for _ in xs():
        for xit, y in zip(xiters, ys()):
            process(next(xit), y)

def grid_of_generators(xs, ys, process):
  x_len = len(list(xs()))
  y_len = len(list(ys()))

  x_cache = [list(xs()) for i in range(0, y_len)]
  y_cache = [list(ys()) for i in range(0, x_len)]

  for xi, yi in product(range(0, x_len), range(0, y_len)):
      process(x_cache[yi][xi], y_cache[xi][yi])

funcs = [
    using_product,
    nested_loops,
    with_deepcopy,
    my_deepcopy,
    one_x_iterator_per_y_value,
    grid_of_generators,
]

from itertools import *
from copy import deepcopy
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random

# The little example
def xs():
    yield [1, 2]
    yield [3, 4]
def ys():
    yield [5, 6]
    yield [7, 8]
def process(x, y):
    print(f'process({x}, {y})')
    x.pop()
    y.pop()
for f in funcs:
    print(f.__name__ + ':')
    f(xs, ys, process)
    print()

# Arguments for benchmark
def xs():
    for _ in range(100):
        yield [1] * 100
ys = xs
def process(x, y):
    pass

# Memory usage
import tracemalloc as tm
for f in funcs * 2:
    tm.start()
    f(xs, ys, process)
    print(f'{tm.get_traced_memory()[1]:10,} bytes ', f.__name__)
    tm.stop()

# Run the benchmark
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(xs, ys, process), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)

Attempt This Online!
